# how to make iteration number in datatables

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable, datatables

how to create a table with datatables where the data comes from the API, I want to add the serial number in each row. all this time I used the id of the data but it was not something good

```
 var Fromuser = $("#tabelAdmin").DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSide: false,
      ajax: "{{route('user.detail')}}",
      columns: [{
          data: "id",
          name: "id"
        }, 
        {
          data: "name",
          name: "name",
          orderable:false
        },
        {
          data: "name_detail",
          name: "name_detail",
          orderable:false
        },
        {
          data: "address",
          name: "address",
          orderable:false
        },
```

Comment: Are you getting this serial number from the ajax call? If so, just add it to the columns.

Comment: no sir, just id, name, full name and address

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like that

1. add one columns to your table (in the beginning)

```
var i = 1;
var Fromuser = $("#tabelAdmin").DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSide: false,
      ajax: "{{route('user.detail')}}",
      columns: [{
          data: null,
          render:function(data , type , row){
          return i++;
          },
       },
       {
          data: "id",
          name: "id"
        }, 
        {
          data: "name",
          name: "name",
          orderable:false
        },
        {
          data: "name_detail",
          name: "name_detail",
          orderable:false
        },
        {
          data: "address",
          name: "address",
          orderable:false
        },
```

it's supposed to solve your problem

Comment: it works but if i delete one of the data and use draw () then i will increase too, so if there is data deleted, the number will increase from 1 to 175

Comment: try `return row.id` instead of `return i++`